# Why @Named dependency is ignored?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have a module that provides `Boolean` value:

```
@Module
class TestModule(private val isTesting: Boolean = false) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(nameIsTesting)
    fun provideIsTesting(): Boolean = isTesting

    // Companion
    companion object {
        const val nameIsTesting = "is_testing"
    }

}
```

`AppComponent`:

```
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class, TestModule::class])
@Singleton
interface AppComponent {

    @Named(TestModule.nameIsTesting)
    val isTesting: Boolean

    // ...
}
```

And build fails:

```
[Dagger/MissingBinding] java.lang.Boolean cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface AppComponent {
                ^
      java.lang.Boolean is provided at
          com.app.app.di.component.AppComponent.isTesting()
```

It works for other dependencies, but not for this one. Why?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this `@Named(TestModule.nameIsTesting) val isTesting: Boolean`?

Comment: Try to annotate the getter method: `@get:Named(TestModule.nameIsTesting)`

Comment: `@field:Named("name")` worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use

```
@Named(TestModule.nameIsTesting)
fun isTesting(): Boolean
```

instead of

```
@Named(TestModule.nameIsTesting)
val isTesting: Boolean
```